# Calculate $\sum_{n=2}^\infty ({n^4+2n^3-3n^2-8n-3\over(n+2)!})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate $\sum_{n=2}^\infty ({n^4+2n^3-3n^2-8n-3\over(n+2)!})$

I thought about maybe breaking the polynomial in two different fractions in order to make the sum more manageable and reduce it to something similar to $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+{1\over1!}+{1\over2!}+...+{1\over n!})$, but didn't manage

Comment: the limit should be $\sum_{n=2}^\infty?$

Comment: oops, sorry, i edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express $$n^4+2n^3-3n^2-8n-3=(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)+B(n+2)(n+1)n+C(n+2)(n+1)+D(n+2)+E--->(1)$$

So that $$T_n=\frac{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-8n-3}{(n+2)!}=\frac1{(n-2)!}+\frac B{(n-1)!}+\frac C{(n)!}+\frac D{(n+1)!}+\frac E{(n+2)!}$$

Putting $n=-2$ in $(1), E=2^4+2\cdot2^3-3\cdot2^2-8\cdot2-3=1$

Similarly, putting  $n=-1,0,1$ we can find $D=0,C=-2,B=0$ .

$$\implies T_n=\frac{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-8n-3}{(n+2)!}=\frac1{(n-2)!}-\frac 2{n!} +\frac 1{(n+2)!}$$

Putting $n=2, T_2=\frac1{0!}-\frac 2{2!} +\frac 1{4!}$

Putting $n=3, T_3=\frac1{1!}-\frac 2{3!} +\frac 1{5!}$

Putting $n=4, T_4=\frac1{2!}-\frac 2{4!} +\frac 1{6!}$

$$\cdots$$

So, the sum will be $$\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac1{r!}-2\sum_{2\le s<\infty}\frac1{s!}+\sum_{4\le t<\infty}\frac1{t!}$$

$=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac1{r!}-2\left(\sum_{0\le s<\infty}\frac1{s!}-\frac1{0!}-\frac1{1!}\right)+\sum_{0\le t<\infty}\frac1{t!}-\left(\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}\right)$

$$=e-2e+e-\{-2\left(\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}\right)+\left(\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}\right)\}=-\frac34$$

Answer (score 0):

First step, we find the Taylor series of $x^4+2x^3-3x^2-8x-3$ at the point $x=-2$ and then use it to write

$$ n^4+2n^3-3n^2-8n-3 = 1-4\, \left( n+2 \right) +9\, \left( n+2 \right)^{2}-6\, \left( n+2
 \right) ^{3}+ \left( n+2 \right) ^{4}.$$

Using the above expansion and shifting the index of summation ($n \longleftrightarrow n-2$ ), we have 
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty {n^4+2n^3-3n^2-8n-3\over(n+2)!}= \sum_{n=2}^\infty {1-4\, \left( n+2 \right) +9\, \left( n+2 \right)^{2}-6\, \left( n+2\right) ^{3}+ \left( n+2 \right)^{4}\over(n+2)!} $$

$$ = \sum_{n=4}^\infty {1-4\,  n  +9\,  n^{2}-6\,  n^{3}+  n^{4} \over n! }+\sum_{n=0}^3 {1-4\,  n  +9\,  n^{2}-6\,  n^{3}+  n^{4} \over n! }$$

$$ -\sum_{n=0}^3 {1-4\,  n  +9\,  n^{2}-6\,  n^{3}+  n^{4} \over n! }$$

$$= c+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty {1-4\,  n  +9\,  n^{2}-6\,  n^{3}+  n^{4} \over n! } $$

$$ = c+e(1-4B_1 + 9 B_2 -6B_3 +B_4),  $$

where $B_n$ are the [bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)

$$ B_n = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{k!}, $$

and $c$ is given by

$$ c=-\sum_{n=0}^3 {1-4\,  n  +9\,  n^{2}-6\,  n^{3}+  n^{4} \over n! }. $$